# Problems with loc function in python, doesn't find a label taht is in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lines-of-code

I have an issue with using the 'loc' function in Python. I would like to extract a specific row from my dataframe 'df', which contains movie titles along with their respective information. The problem is that when I use 'df.loc['movie title']', I receive the following error as if it doesn't exist in the DataFrame, even though it does. Let me show you an example:

df.set_index('title')

## And here i receive the correct output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWmPl.png)

as you can see Toy Story in in DataFrame df but when i try to print all his rae with loc i receive this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irIpi.png)

I use pd.loc['Toy Story'] but python say that in my df there isn't any 'Toy story' label
Can someone give me an explanation of this?

Comment: did you save the dataframe after setting the index? if yes, can print `df.index` and show us the output

Comment: I don't think that i "save" the dataframe, i just set a new index in order to have the title colum as new index and then print it. I try to print df.index and the answer is : RangeIndex(start=0, stop=44691, step=1).

Comment: posted the answer, please check

Comment: `df.loc('Toy Story')` means that you want to get a `loc` accessor for the 'Toy Story's **axis**, use `df.loc['Toy Story']` (square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the changes to the dataframe. Can you try the following:

```
df = df.set_index('title')
```

Comment: Yes i try to save the df.set_index and now df.loc[''] works ! Sorry for stupid question but i reallly don't understand what was the problem